# getline skipping first input character c++

Tags: c++, loops, getline

So I have been making this program for a while now. I have looked all over the internet and none of the solutions I have found work. Every time I put in my input in the arr[i].question and arr[i].answer, it says that my question is wrong without me giving a answer to the question. I have tried using cin.ignore(), cin.clear(), and cin.sync(). I might have been using them in the wrong places but i'm not sure. I might be confusing, so just look at the code.

Here is the input format.

```
    cin >> count;
cin.ignore();

for(int i =0; i < count; i++){
    cout << "Enter the question.\n" << endl;
    //enter the question

    getline(cin, arr[i].question);
    cin.ignore();

    cout << "Enter the answer.\n" << endl;
    //enter the answer

    getline (cin, arr[i].answer);
    cin.ignore();

}
```

and here is the out put format to quiz you.

```
    for(int j =0; j < count; j++){
    cout << "\n" << arr[j].question << endl;
    getline(cin, userguess);

    if(arr[j].answer.compare(userguess) !=0){
        cout << "Wrong. Keep trying!\n";
        incorrect++;
        total++;
    }
    if(arr[j].answer.compare(userguess) ==0){
        cout << "Nice job. Keep it up!\n";
        correct++;
        total++;
    }
```

Whenever I put in my question it doesn't output a question in the console or let me put in an answer. It just says wrong.
A little help please?

edit: here is the whole code:

```
// final PROJECT.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct flashcards{
string question;
string answer;
}FC1, FC2, FC3, FC4, FC5, FC6, FC7, FC8, FC9, FC10, FC11, FC12, FC13, FC14, FC15, FC16, FC17, FC18, FC19, FC20;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

{
system ("color 4B");
string userguess;
string again;
flashcards arr[10000];
int count;
float correct=0;
float incorrect=0;
float total=0;
//one major problem, wont accept spaces.
cout<< "Flash Card Runner\n";
cout<< "This program was made by Jacob Malcy\n";
cout<< "Beta 3.8\n";
cout<< "IN ORDER FOR YOU TO HAVE MULTIPLE WORD FLASH CARDS,\n";
cout << "SKIP NUMBER ONE FLASHCARD QUESTION AND ANSWER!\n";
cout<< "This bug is currently being worked on.\n";
cout << "If you happen to have problems conntact Jacob.\n";
int choice;


cout<< "Would you like to create or test? Enter 0 for create and 1 for test.\n";
cin >> choice;
if(choice==0){
    //Creating new deck of cards
cout<< "How many flashcards do you want?\n";
cin >> count;
cin.clear();

for(int i =0; i < count; i++){
    cout << "Enter the question.\n" << endl;
    //enter the question

    getline(cin, arr[i].question);
    cin.ignore();

    cout << "Enter the answer.\n" << endl;
    //enter the answer

    getline (cin, arr[i].answer);
    cin.ignore();

}
}
else if(choice==1){
    //Reading in new file
    cout << "Reading file...\n";

    string line;
    ifstream myfile ("Save.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        count = 0;

        while ( myfile.good () )
        {
            getline (myfile,line);
            arr[count].question = line;
            cout << line << endl;

        getline (myfile,line);
        arr[count].answer = line;
        cout << line << endl;
        count++;

        }

        myfile.close();
    }

    else cout << "Unable to open the file";
}

do
{

for(int j =0; j < count; j++){
    cout << "\n" << arr[j].question << endl;
    getline(cin, userguess);

    if(arr[j].answer.compare(userguess) !=0){
        cout << "Wrong. Keep trying!\n";
        incorrect++;
        total++;
    }
    if(arr[j].answer.compare(userguess) ==0){
        cout << "Nice job. Keep it up!\n";
        correct++;
        total++;
    }


}
cout<< "The number of correct questions answered was: \n" << correct << endl;
cout<<"The number of total questions answered was: " << total <<"\n";
    cout<< "The number of incorrect questions answered was: \n" << incorrect << endl;
    //cout<< total;
    float percent = (correct/total)*100;
    cout<< "The total percent you got right is: \n" << percent << "% correct" << endl;
    system("pause");
    cout << "Would you like to run the quiz again?\n"
    << "Type y or Y to run this again. If not, enter any other letter.\n";
    cin >> again;
    if((again == "y") || (again == "Y")){
    correct=0;
    incorrect=0;
    total=0;
    }

}while((again == "y") || (again == "Y"));

ofstream myfile ("Save.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{

    for(int i =0; i <count; i++){

        myfile << arr[i].question << "\n";
        myfile << arr[i].answer << "\n";
    }
    myfile.close();

    }
else cout << "Unable to save file";

cout << "Your finished with the quiz. Goodbye!\n";

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

When I run it, it comes out like this

```
    Flash Card Runner
This program was made by Jacob Malcy
Beta 3.8
IN ORDER FOR YOU TO HAVE MULTIPLE WORD FLASH CARDS,
SKIP NUMBER ONE FLASH CARD QUESTION AND ANSWER!
This is a bug is currently being worked on.
if you happen to have problems, conntact Jacob.
Would you like to create or test? Enter 0 for create and 1 for test.
```

If i enter zero:

```
How many flashcards do you want?
```

say I enter two 2

```
Enter the question.

Hi ho
Enter the answer.

Merry oh

enter the question.

fi fa
enter the answer.

fo fum
```

then it just skips to:

```
Wrong. Keep trying!

erry oh
```

Before wrong, it should display the first question, and give me the oppertunity to answer.
It just says wrong before i can. then it displays the answer with the first character missing. There you go.

Comment: `cin.sync` is not guaranteed to do what it says, so I wouldn't rely on that behaviour.

Comment: It's not at all to me clear what you are saying. Could be post a complete program and state clearly what you input and what you see in the console. Just cut and paste the whole program, and the whole console session. And jrok is correct, cin.ignore() is either incorrect or sub-optimal on all the occasions you are using it. cin.sync() and cin.clear() are irrelevant. I guess you read all those posts on the internet without gaining an understanding of the issue.

Comment: Alright here is the whole code.

Comment: Jrok, when I get rid of any cin.ignore();, it simply skips all of the input and only states the output. And yeah i'm trying to get rid of the newline. I just cant figure out why it skips.

Answer (score 7):

I presume you're calling `ignore` right after `getline` to get rid of the trailing newline character.

Do not do that. `std::getline` already extracts the newline character from the stream (and discards it), so you're ignoring the first character of the next line.